# CodeIgniter view referencing previous view's call variables

Tags: php, codeigniter, templates, codeigniter-2

I've got a problem I have only recently noticed in my code ingiter app. I've stripped down the issue to try to locate the problem, but i'm still lost.

I have the following view (template/assets/box):

```
<div class="box <? if(isset($class)){echo $class;} ?>">

    <?
    if(isset($boxtitle) || isset($titleimg)){
        ?>
        <div class="head">
            <? if(isset($boxtitle)){ echo '<h3>'.$boxtitle.'</h3>';} ?>
            <? if(isset($titleimg)){ echo '<img src="'.$titleimg.'" />';} ?>
        </div>
        <?
        $has_head = 1;
    }
    ?>

    <div class="content <? if(!isset($has_head)){ echo 'border-top';}?> <? if(!isset($footer)){ echo 'border-bottom';}?>">
        <?
        if(isset($type)){
            switch($type){
                case 'list':
                    echo '<ul class="list" >';
                    foreach($items as $item){
                        ?>
                        <li><?=$item; ?></li>
                        <?
                    }
                    echo '</ul>';
                    break;
                case 'grid':
                    break;
                default:
                    echo '<div class="item">'.$content.'</div>';
                    break;
            }
        }
        else{
            echo '<div class="item">'.$content.'</div>';
        }

        ?>

    </div>


        <? 
        if(isset($footer)){
            ?><div class="footer <? if(isset($items)){echo 'border-top';} ?> "><?
            echo $footer; 
            ?></div><?
        } 
        ?>


</div>
```

Then, for debugging purposes, i've adding the following into a controller:

```
public function index(){

        // page data
        $data['page_title'] = 'Directories';

        // load template and output
        $this->load->view('template/assets/box',array('boxtitle'=>'foo','content'=>'bar')); 
        $this->load->view('template/assets/box',array('content'=>'blah'));
        $this->load->view('template/assets/box',array());
        #$this->Template_model->view('directories/index',$data);
    }
```

however, when I load this controller, I get the following:

```
<div class="box ">

            <div class="head">
            <h3>foo</h3>                    </div>

    <div class="content  border-bottom">
        <div class="item">bar</div>
    </div>




</div>


<div class="box ">

            <div class="head">
            <h3>foo</h3>                    </div>

    <div class="content  border-bottom">
        <div class="item">blah</div>
    </div>




</div>


<div class="box ">

            <div class="head">
            <h3>foo</h3>                    </div>

    <div class="content  border-bottom">
        <div class="item">blah</div>
    </div>




</div>
```

Basically, each call to the view seems to cascade the previous variables to the view unless overwritten. Is this a bug in codeigniter? Is it something that maybe PHP or CI config might be causing issues? I can't think of anything I've done which might have caused this problem.

Comment: if you are done with variable just `unset()` it

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's a feature. Sequential view loads have access to all the previous variables that you passed to the previous views.

Here's a comment from the CI source code that sorta demonstrates this fact:

[/system/core/Loader.php:840](https://github.com/EllisLab/CodeIgniter/blob/develop/system/core/Loader.php)

```
/*
* Extract and cache variables
*
* You can either set variables using the dedicated $this->load->vars()
* function or via the second parameter of this function. We'll merge
* the two types and cache them so that views that are embedded within
* other views can have access to these variables.
*/
```

Comment: Could you link to any reference of this in documentation, or code comment regarding this?

Comment: @RobinCastlin, no, sorry. Only based on past experience. It has always worked like this. You could always ask the codeigniter community itself for clarification, but that's the way it works.

Comment: If dug it out myself: `/system/core/Loader.php` line 800.

Comment: @RobinCastlin, Cheers, incorporated that actual quote into the answer.